# Laravel hasOne Huge Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I cant seem to pull out the cat name from another model.

My array looks fine when I get all the items as below.

```
  $testing = Scraper::get();
  print_r($testing);

   [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Scraper Object
                (
                    .....
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [cat_id] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2014-08-18 09:08:54
                            [updated_at] => 2014-08-18 09:08:54
                      .....
                        )
```

When I try the code bellow as a print_r I get a huge array of nothing related to pulling the item with it's categories name?

Scraper::first()->categorie();

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne Object
(
    [foreignKey:protected] => categories.scraper_id
    [localKey:protected] => id
    [query:protected] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder Object
        (
            [query:protected] => Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder Object
                ( 
                 .....
```

Have I done something wrong, my models are below.

**Cat.php**

```
class Cat extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'categories';

}
```

**Scraper.php**

```
class Scraper extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'scraper';

    public function categorie() {
        return $this->hasOne('Cat');
    }

}
```

**Databases**

```
categories -  | id | name

scraper - |id | cat_id | updated_at | created_at
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call:

```
Scraper::first()->categorie;
```

instead of:

```
Scraper::first()->categorie();
```

Explanation: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#dynamic-properties